# How to Allow New Relic IP with UFW?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, newrelic

from this article: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/getting-started/networks

it suggests me to allow outgoing firewall with following ips and ports:

### Networks

50.31.164.0/24
162.247.240.0/22

### Ports

TCP 80
TCP 443

I'm using ufw, how can i do it?

I've tried this: 
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  50.31.164.0/24 port 80
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  50.31.164.0/24 port 443
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  162.247.240.0/22 port 80
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  162.247.240.0/22 port 443

When I check my rules: they are like this:

[image]

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

You already allow connections from anywhere to 80 & 443, so you don't need the extra allow statements for their specific IP ranges.

The request for outgoing connections is if you are running say your corporate site through it but are filtering outgoing traffic from your LAN (ie, only being able to get to a schools website from a kiosk in their hallway or from a lab) and you want people on your local network to be able to access it.